# SSL/TLS Protocol version in Javaee

Tags: java, internet-explorer, ssl, servlets

Is there any way in Java EE to know what SSL/TLS protocol is being used for a secure connection?

Ideally I want the application to use TLS/1.2 for everything, but I know some browswers (ie 9 say) by default wont support that.  If I configure my enviroment to only allow TLS/1.2 then IE 9 will go "ohh this website is down", if you then click help, advance it actually tells you "oh this might be that the settings in IE disable sensible encryption, you and do this to enable sensible encryption". (I am paraphrasing slightly).

Anyway the response is a cold, "website down", which is not true, its just IE does not wish to support sensible protocols.  My preference would be to change the configuration to allow weaker protocols like TLS/1.0, my application can then detect that a weak protocol is being used and on every page there can be some sort of warning "you know this is not secure, click here for more information", ie a helpful message that confirms that the website is working, just their browser is insecure.  I cant see any attributes that form part of HttpServletRequest that might give me this information or any other method that answers the question.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get the TLS protocol compatibility upfront.

How about checking for browser and its version in the request.
If any of the browsers (like you had mentioned ie) are having issues with it, then send that Warning message of yours in the response along with the actual content.

You can get the browser info using:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

Also, you could probably look up some answers for achieving this using javascript. As it resides at client end, it could be used to handle such scenario's.

Comment: Unfortunatly the User-Agent is not reliable, as you can be using Internet Explorer 8 which support TLS 1.2, but by default will specifically request to use an insecure protocol.  So just because its IE 8 does not mean its insecure. JavaScript is not the ideal option because its easy to disable and it means the check is client side therefore easier to work arround.